# Android Wear notification showing minimized

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the notification is the way I like it but I cannot get it to make the watch vibrate, and it shows as minimized. the effect I want to achieve should look like hangouts notification, which vibrate and go fullscreen. here is the code I'm using (on the watch):

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, ConvActivity.class);
            actionIntent.putExtra("num",num);
            PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Create the action
                NotificationCompat.Action action =
                        new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Reply"
                                , actionPendingIntent)
                                .build();
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            bigStyle.bigText(body).setBigContentTitle(name);


            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(name)
                            .setContentText(body)
                                    //.setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
                                    //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_map,
                                    //        getString(R.string.map), mapPendingIntent)
                            .setStyle(bigStyle).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Reply"
                            , actionPendingIntent);

            if(pic != null)
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pic,0,pic.length));
                            //.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action))                ;




            // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// Issue the notification with notification manager.
                notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only notifications that vibrate/sound will vibrate an Android Wear device and show more text.

You should consider using the [NotificationCompat.Builder.setDefaults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDefaults(int)) method:

```
// Light, sound, and vibrate
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
// Just sound
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
// Just vibrate
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
```